# Variable declaration in BEGIN block

Tags: perl

In a script like the following, is it possible without dropping 'my' to effectively declare 'var' only once and have it visible outside the BEGIN block?

```
echo -e "\n\n\n" | \
  perl -lne 'BEGIN { my $var="declared & initialized once" } print $var'
```

Also, why declaring var without 'my' makes it visible outside the BEGIN block?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Place a `my $var;` before the `BEGIN` block:

```
$ perl -le 'my $var; BEGIN { $var = "declared"; } print $var;'
declared
```

`my` gives the variable lexical scope, so `$var` is not defined in your example outside the `BEGIN` block. Removing the `my` effectively makes it a global variable, which is accessible across the script after assignment.

Comment: The compilation order puzzles me a little. Since $var is declared in the BEGIN block first, why is it not erased by the declaration with `my` later?

Answer (score 2):

> Also, why declaring var without 'my' makes it visible outside the BEGIN block?

You're not declaring it then. It is autodeclared as global, if you're not using `use strict` (which prevents the declaration by default). In a one-liner, `strict` hurts more than it helps; I'm perfectly fine with not doing a declaration in such a context.